# Finding GCD using arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, greatest-common-divisor

Hi I am trying to write a code in C to find the GCD for more than 2 numbers. However, when I compile and run the code, the GCD is always 0. Would appreciate if anyone can help. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int gcd(int x, int y)
{
  int r;
  if (x <= 0 || y <= 0)
    return 0;

  while ((r = x % y) != 0)
    {
      x = y;
      y = r;
    }
    return y;
}

int main (void)
{
  int A[5];
  int g = A[0];
  int i;
  int n;

  printf ("How many elements are there? \n")
  scanf ("%d", &n);

  printf ("Input the elements. \n");

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      scanf ("%d", &A[i]);
    }

  for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
    g = gcd(g, A[i]);

    printf ("GCD is: %d \n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. What help do you need? Have you tried adding logging? Have you tried using a debugger? What did you get stuck on?

Comment: int g = A[0]; second statement inside main function, does it make sense? You are assigning a garbage value in the variable g.

Answer (score 2):

You set `g` equal to `A[0]` before you set `A[0]` to any particular value.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `;` after the first `printf`.
You need to declare `A` with `n` elements after you read the number of elements `n`.
You have to write the `g` after `",` in your last `printf`.

This is how I think your main should look like:

```
int main (void)
{
    int i;
    int n;

    printf ("How many elements are there? \n");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    int A[n];

    printf ("Input the elements. \n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      scanf ("%d", &A[i]);
    }

    int g = A[0];
    for (i = 1; i < n; i++)
        g = gcd(g, A[i]);

    printf ("GCD is: %d", g);

    return 0;
}
```